# prevent bakspace event in web browser

Tags: javascript, gwt

When I press Backspace, Web-browser will go to previous page. How can I disable it only for this issue but backspace must work for text box .this problem in firefox 28
please give answer in gwt or java script

Answer (score 0):

**I got this example try this:**

**pure javascript:**

```
function suppressBackspace(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

    if (evt.keyCode == 8 && !/input|textarea/i.test(target.nodeName)) {
        return false;
    }
}

document.onkeydown = suppressBackspace;
document.onkeypress = suppressBackspace;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
RootPanel.get().addDomHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
            if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }, KeyUpEvent.getType());
```